# c Specific Date to Time

Tags: c, date, seconds, time-t

I want to convert from specific date to seconds in C. For example, If I give 12/25/2015, it will convert into seconds.
This is the program I found to convert current date to seconds. But I want to convert from specific date to seconds.

```
time_t timer;
  struct tm y2k;
  double seconds;

  y2k.tm_hour = 0;   y2k.tm_min = 0; y2k.tm_sec = 0;
  y2k.tm_year = 0; y2k.tm_mon = 0; y2k.tm_mday = 1;

  time(&timer);  

  seconds = difftime(timer,mktime(&y2k));

  printf ("%.f ", seconds);
```

Comment: C++ or C? Your code seems to be C, not C++

Answer (score 0):

The result of [`mktime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html) is the number of seconds (give or take a few leap seconds) since midnight 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

This is also know as [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: I don't know how to easily get a value more precise than Unix Time provides.

Answer (score 0):

Read the man page on the tm structure (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/).  For 25 Dec 2015,

```
y2k.tm_year = 2015 - 1900; /* Starts from 1900 */
y2k.tm_mon = 12 - 1; /* Jan = 0 */
y2k.tm_mday = 15;
```

Also, to print a double, use %lf.  You may not get the result you want if you just use %f.

Comment: `"%f"` or "`%lf`" have exactly the same meaning in `printf()`, since C99 (they differ in `scanf()`).

Answer (score 0):

You might also find *strptime(3)* useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    char format[] = "%m/%d/%y";
    char input[] = "12/25/15";
    char buf[256];
    struct tm tm;

    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof tm);

    if (strptime(input, format, &tm) == NULL) {
         fputs("strptime failed\n", stderr);
         return 1;
    }

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d %b %Y %H:%M", &tm);

    printf("reformatted: %s; as time_t: %ld\n", buf, mktime(&tm));

    return 0;
}
```